# How to make files in connected FTP server folder open in default program

Tags: windows, ftp

I own an Ubuntu based FTP server. It is connected to several Windows machines under "Network Locations". The connection is fine and always shows the latest files I release.

However, I can't get these files to open in any program other than my web browser. It doesn't matter if it's plain text or some other format: anything in this FTP folder opens in the browser.

I can copy items out of the folder, then they open in the correct program.

I need these files to open in the default application without first copying them to a different location. How can I do this?

Comment: You can edit the handler for ftp protocol (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftp\shell\open\command, change default to some near `CMD /c start "%1"` and remove DelegateExecute key) using regedit, of course, but I recommend You **NOT** to do this strongly. Maybe, create .CMD file with command line shown and drag'n'drop the file to it from explorer window is enough?

Comment: This is not a viable solution for me. I can't suggest my users to modify their registers, only minor settings changes in the ftp folder, or on my server end are acceptable.

I am not sure what you mean by your second suggestion but to me it sounds like it would require manual steps each time comparable to just dragging the files elsewhere

Comment: *only minor settings changes in the ftp folder, or on my server end are acceptable* Filetypes/protocols associations is absolutely inner property of the client station OS. I can not even imagine myself for the way to solve Your problem.